# ReDim Preserve results in mistake

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that takes a range of cells as an argument and checks how many of these cells contain '2' or '3', then gives a message box with a determined text.
The problem is with the dynamic array. If I use an array of a fixed length, everything works fine. But once I employed the ReDim Preserve method, the function doesn't return any value in the cell and doesn't display a message box...
What's wrong here?

```
Function test2(Var As Range)
          Dim result0 As Integer
          Dim resultsFinal() As Long
          ReDim resultsFinal(0)
          Dim i As Integer

          i = 0

          result = 0

          Dim cell As Range
          For Each cell In Var.Cells
                  If cell.Value = 2 Or cell.Value = 3 Then
                         result = result + 1
                         ReDim Preserve resultsFinal(result)
                         resultsFinal(i) = cell.Row
                         i = i + 1
                         test2 = cell.Value
          End If
          Next cell

          MsgBox result & "and  " & vbNewLine &   
          array: " & Join(resultsFinal, ", ")

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JOIN command only works with strings or variant.

If you change to a STRING and fix a couple of typos it works fine

```
Function test2(Var As Range)
  Dim result As Integer
  Dim resultsFinal() As String
  ReDim resultsFinal(0)
  Dim i As Integer

  i = 0

  result = 0

  Dim cell As Range
  For Each cell In Var.Cells
          If cell.Value = 2 Or cell.Value = 3 Then
                 result = result + 1
                 ReDim Preserve resultsFinal(result)
                 resultsFinal(i) = cell.Row
                 i = i + 1
                 test2 = cell.Value
  End If
  Next cell

  MsgBox result & "and  " & vbNewLine & " array: " & Join(resultsFinal, ", ")
End Function
```

Comment: Any chance you know how to prevent it from printing out that last comma after the last element?

Comment: Yes, it's happening because you're setting the array one bigger than it needs to be each time, so you're left with a final orphan empty array element. You can just move the result accumulator to after setting resultsFinal and get ride of the variable i altogether, so: `resultsFinal(result) = cell.Row`
`      result = result + 1`